# Why doesn't PHP print TRUE/FALSE?

Tags: php

Given the following test.php:

```
<?php

echo TRUE . "\n";    // prints "1\n"
echo FALSE . "\n";   // prints "\n"

?>
```

Why doesn't `php -f test.php` print `TRUE` or `FALSE`? More importantly, in the `FALSE` case, why doesn't it print anything?

Comment: `echo "TRUE";`, `echo "FALSE";` ?

Comment: The latter is by design. It should output `1` for true though

Comment: This is because `C` has no `boolean` but uses `0` for `FALSE` and everything else for `TRUE`. And PHP uses a lot of `C` concepts. Therefore you can use `if($foo)` in PHP which evaluates to `true` in every case when `$foo` is set, not empty and not `0` or `false`.

Comment: @AgnelKurian `echo ($foo ? "TRUE" : "FALSE") ;`

Answer (score 40, accepted):

From the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php):

> A boolean TRUE value is converted to the string "1". Boolean FALSE is converted to "" (the empty string). This allows conversion back and forth between boolean and string values.

Comment: I think that what most of us asking this question weren't thinking about was "...allows conversion back and forth..."

Comment: null is also not printable in PHP, is null is also converted to empty String ?

Comment: @Muhammad Yes it is.

Answer (score 23):

Because `false == '';`

do this to print booleans:

```
$bool = false;
echo $bool ? 'true' : 'false';
```

or...

```
echo $bool ? 'yes' : 'no';
echo $bool ? '1' : '0';
```

Answer (score 8):

Because boolean values when cast to a string are cast to `1` and an empty string respectively.

Supposedly this is to enable a transparent roundtrip between boolean -> string -> boolean.